# How to solve equation and save in right way?

Tags: c++

I am new learner in c++. So actually I will try to find out the total force, velocity, location and total time in every time step (dt=0.00001) and save myfile1, myfile2, myfile3, myfile4 from solve simple equation. I am facing problem to find out the exact value. When I run the program the segmentation fault error is found. So how can I solve the problem? I am attached the program given below: Anybody can help me?

```
//C++ programming for selection random number
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>


//%stifness
double kp=1000;
//%gravitational
double g=-9.81;


    double x[10000], y[10000], z[10000];
    double Fx[10000],Fy[10000],  Fz[10000];
    double vx[10000],vy[10000], vz[10000] ;
    double ax[10000],ay[10000], az[10000] ;
    double force[10000];
    const double PI=4.0*atan(1.0); 

    using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
//open output file
    ofstream myfile1;
    myfile1.open("1.dat");
    ofstream myfile2;
    myfile2.open("2.dat");
    ofstream myfile3;
    myfile3.open("3.dat");
    ofstream myfile4;
    myfile4.open("4.dat");


// %particle parameter

double  dt=1e-5;
double Ntimestep=1000;

//particle properties
    double R=0.003;
    double Dens=2600;
        int npart=1;

//Particle Creation 
        double Mass=(Dens*4*PI*(pow(R,3))/3);    //m=(4/3)* Dens*Pi*R^3
        cout<<"Mass="<< Mass<<endl;

//initial position of the particle

        x[0]=0;
            y[0] =0.01;
            z[0] =0;

// movement of the particle
// Particle initial velocity and forces
     Fx[0]=0;
     Fy[0]=0; 
     Fz[0]=0;
     vx[0]=0;
     vy[0]=-0.5;
     vz[0]=0;
     force[0]=0;

// Relation between dashport coefficient and coefficient of restitution
     double exp=0.9;
     double lnexp=0.10536;
     double Eta= ((2*sqrt(Mass*kp)*lnexp)/(sqrt(pow(PI,2)+pow(lnexp,2))));

//Time step
    int t=0;
for (int i=0;i<Ntimestep;i++)
{

// calculate particle to wall contact force

       if (y[i]<R)
            {
                Fy[i]=(-kp*(y[i]-R))-Eta*vy[i];
            }

// Calculate initial acceleration

        ay[i]=(Fy[i]/Mass)+g;
//force[i]+=force[1];
        force[i+1]=ay[i]*Mass;
        //cout<<"Total_Force="<<force<<endl;

// update valocity and displacement/location

    vy[i+1]=(vy[i]+(ay[i]*dt));
    y[i+1]=y[i]+vy[i]*dt+0.5*ay[i]*pow(dt,2);
    Fy[i]=0;

    t=t+1;

     double time=t*dt;



//...............output/save file..............................

cout<<"Total force="<<force<<endl;
myfile1<<"Total force="<<force<<endl;

cout<<"velocity="<<vy<<endl;
myfile2<<"velocity="<<vy<<endl;

cout<<"location="<<y<<endl;
myfile3<<"location="<<y<<endl;

cout<<"Total time"<<time<<endl;
myfile4<<"Total time="<<time<<endl;

}


//system ("PAUSE");
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    myfile1.close();
    myfile2.close();
    myfile3.close();
    myfile4.close();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about the error? It works without any problems on my system. By the way, it's not a good idea to print too many values and results to the output console.

Comment: You probably want to output `force[i]`, `vy[i]` and `y[i]`

Comment: What happens when you step through in the debugger?

Comment: Thanks Anton Savin

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your original value for `Ntimestep` was `10000` (the dimension of your C-style arrays `x`, `y`, `z`, `Fx`, `Fy`, `Fz`, `vx`, `vy`, `vz` and `force`), not the actual `1000`.

With the actual `Ntimestep = 1000`, I don't see occasions for a segmentation fault; but with `Ntimestep = 10000`, when `i` in the `for` cycle is 9999 (last iteration), in the following instructions

```
force[i+1]=ay[i]*Mass;
vy[i+1]=(vy[i]+(ay[i]*dt));
y[i+1]=y[i]+vy[i]*dt+0.5*ay[i]*pow(dt,2);
```

you write in `force`, in `vy` and in `y` in position 10000. And this is bad (your a learner of C++ but I suppose that you know that you can read/write an `X x[n]` array from `0` to `n-1` and that an access in `x[n]` is an out of bound access).

Some advices, in no particolar order

1) take care of indentation; your code is difficult to read

2) avoid, if possible, global variables

3) use, when you can, constants (`constexpr`, when possible, if you use C++11/C++14); global constants are good and you can define array sizes with they; by example, you can define a global constant

```
 const int  numSteps = 10000;
```

and the array definition (local in `main()`, i suggest) can be

```
 double x[numSteps+1], y[numSteps+1], z[numSteps+1];
 double Fx[numSteps+1],Fy[numSteps+1],  Fz[numSteps+1];
 double vx[numSteps+1],vy[numSteps+1], vz[numSteps+1] ;
 double ax[numSteps+1],ay[numSteps+1], az[numSteps+1] ;
 double force[numSteps+1];
```

(`+1` to give the arrays another position and avoid the problem above) and the `for` cycle can be

```
 for (int i=0;i<numSteps;i++)
```

4) take in consideration the hypothesis to use `std::vector<double>` (with `resize(numSteps+1)`) instead of C-style arrays; with a `std::vector`, using `at()` instead of `[i]`, you'd have an exception and you would have found out immediately the out of bound error

4 bis) if you are using C++11/C++14, `std::array<double, numSteps+1>` can be a better solution than `std::vector<double>`

p.s.: sorry for my bad English